# Can you use Azure Active Directory as a credential for Elastic Queries for Azure Databases?

Tags: sql, database, azure

I was wondering if this was supported yet? I see most examples show creating an SQL user as their credential to connect Azure Databases for Elastic Queries, but some of these examples are years old.

An Example:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE RemoteReferenceData
WITH
(
 TYPE=RDBMS,
 LOCATION='myserver.database.windows.net',
 DATABASE_NAME='ReferenceData',
 CREDENTIAL= SqlUser
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CREDENTIAL` you mention in `CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE` is actually `DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL` which is a prerequisite before creating the **EXTERNAL TABLE** for which you will run Elastic Queries.

Unfortunately, **authentication using Azure Active Directory with elastic queries is not currently supported.** So either you use SQL User or `SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE` if the file is stored in Azure Blob Storage.

Refer [Get started with cross-database queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-getting-started-vertical?view=azuresql#database-scoped-master-key-and-credentials) for the supported statement and other details.